# JavaScript Number.MAX_VALUE > 2^64

Tags: javascript, types

In JavaScript, the Number data type is [64 bits long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17320771/3097454).

How then is `Number.MAX_VALUE === 1.7976931348623157e+308` and `Math.pow(2, 64) === 18446744073709552000`? 
How can the Number data type only be 64 bits, but have a higher value than 2^64?

Also I noticed that `Math.pow(2, 64) + 1 === Math.pow(2, 64)` but `Math.pow(2, 64) + 10000 !== Math.pow(2, 64)`  Why would 2^64 + 1 be equal to 2^64 and 2^64 + 10000 not?

Comment: 64-bit *floating point* numbers. Re-read both the question and the answer, and see the result of `Math.pow(2, 64) + 10000`. It has a lot of 0s at the end, which the actual result of `2^64 + 10000` doesn't have.

Comment: You can try this to see that the calculation is not exact: `Math.pow(2, 64) + 10000 - 10000 == Math.pow(2,64)`, it will return `false`.

Comment: Because `Number` in JavaScript are floating-point numbers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439981/661843 how to avoid this problem.

Comment: In floating point numbers, 11 bits are reserved for the exponent, 52 bits for the mantissa.  Making the number larger than what can be represented by 52 bits means a loss of precision.

Comment: How come the MAX_VALUE is much much larger than 2^64?

Comment: Because the 11-bit exponent can go 10^(+/- 308).  The mantissa is still restricted to 52 bits, though, so the end of the number will start filling with zeroes.

Comment: @Amy Thank you and yes it does.